# How to use Nunit3 project file in TeamCity

Tags: nunit, teamcity, nunit-3.0, teamcity-10

I want to specify my own NUnit project file (.nunit file) on Teamcity, but I do not see any option to do that. Teamcity generates its own .nunit file based on assemblies mentioned.

But having my own .nunit file allows me maintain several configurations.

Is there a way to specify custom NUnit project file in TeamCity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out TeamCity internally supports NUnit3. So I do not have to use Nunit build step to run NUnit tests. I can simply use a Commandline step and get the same results. It gives me more flexibility then using NUnit build step.

Here is the source:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2015/11/teamcity-and-nunit-3/